# Survival analysis with cluster data

Tags: r, time-series, survival, cox-model

I am performing a survival analysis with cluster data cluster(id) using GEE in R (package:survival).

I was wondering I could correctly interpret the Robust value in the summary of the model output.

Robust = 14.65  p=0.4

thanks in advance

Comment: check the documentation for that package

Comment: There is no information about that in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

For a robust model involving a `cluster` term, this is reported as an overall test of model significance along with the Likelihood ratio, Wald, and Score (log-rank) tests. It can be hard to find specific documentation on the Robust term, but its meaning is clear from the underlying code for `survival:::print.summary.coxph` and `survival:::summary.coxph`.

The "Robust" value represents a robust Score test value for the model as a whole. The associated p-value has the usual interpretation: the probability that a test value at least that large might be found by chance even if the null model holds. For this example, the interpretation would be that the model was not significantly different from the null model.